# How to verify CAN interfaces with Linux?

Tags: linux, verification, canbus

I want to verify the CAN interfaces on my embedded system. It has two can ports: `can0` and `can1`.

I bring them both up with the following sequence:

```
# ip link set can0 type can bitrate 1000000 dbitrate 2000000 fd on
# ip link set can0 up
# ip link set can1 type can bitrate 1000000 dbitrate 2000000 fd on
# ip link set can1 up
```

I hooked them up to each other (`CANH`<->`CANH`, `CANL`<->`CANL` & `GND`<->`GND`) with termination resistors on each side after the trabnsceivers.
Now when I want to send traffic out on `can0` and dump rthe incoming traffic on `can1`.

I started `candump -c -a any` while I invoke:

```
# cansend can0 01a#11223344AABBCCDD
```

But after this, I get a bunch of kernel errors that look like:

```
[ 1506.337694] rcar_canfd 10050000.can can0: ch erfl 401 txerr 128 rxerr 0
[ 1506.337702] rcar_canfd 10050000.can can0: Bus error
[ 1506.337707] rcar_canfd 10050000.can can0: ACK Error
```

Appears like `128` stands for `CAN_ERROR_PASSIVE_THRESHOLD` which indicates that about which I read:

> **Error Passive**: In this state, the CAN node is still able to transmit data, but it now raises 'Passive Error Flags' when detecting
> errors. Further, the CAN node now has to wait for an extra 8 bits (aka
> Suspend Transmission Time) in addition to the 3 bit intermission time
> before it can resume data transmission (to allow other CAN nodes to
> take control of the bus)

source: [https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/can-bus-errors-intro-tutorial#:~:text=A%20CAN%20node%20enters%20the,if%20the%20TEC%20exceeds%20255](https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/can-bus-errors-intro-tutorial#:%7E:text=A%20CAN%20node%20enters%20the,if%20the%20TEC%20exceeds%20255)

There's nothing showing with `candump`, though. The above messages show up in `dmesg`.
But I still can see data on the CAN lines (with a scope).

What do the errors mean, how can I address them  and how can I actually see data with `candump`?